# ORACLE SQL get difference of two values retrieved from 2 select statements

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle10g

We have 2 very simple SELECT statements:

```
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
```

We need a way to write a single SQL statement which will get the difference of the "value" that is returned from these two SQL statements.

We tried the following but it was not successful:

```
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
minus 
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the numeric difference (provided that both SELECTs return only one row)? Or do you want the set difference (i.e. all values returned from statement1 that are not returned from statement2)?

Comment: Then you should accept trideceth12's answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Untested but should work:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2) - 
    (SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4)
FROM dual;
```

Assuming that your `SELECT value` is guaranteed to return a single value

Comment: what to do, if there is no single value?

Comment: @Beezy The questioner asked about getting the difference between two values. If your select gets more than one value each, you need to add more conditions until you get only the values you intend to be included in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT value FROM TBL WHERE date BETWEEN DATE1 and DATE2 
AND value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM TBL WHERE date BETWEEN DATE3 AND DATE4)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you think your inner queries can give multiple values, use below

```
SELECT
    (SELECT sum(value) from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2) - 
    (SELECT sum(value) from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4) as answer
FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
V_FIRST NUMBER := 0;
V_SECOND NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT value into V_FIRST from table where rownum=1 and date between DATE1 and DATE2;
  SELECT value into V_SECOND from table where rownum=1 and date between DATE3 and DATE4;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (V_FIRST-V_SECOND); 
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
 minus 
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
)
union all
(
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
 minus 
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below statement should work for your case

```
(
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
 minus 
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
)
union
(
SELECT value from table where date between DATE1 and DATE2
 minus 
SELECT value from table where date between DATE3 and DATE4
)
```