# Find new students in August but not there in July from same table Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have STUDENTS table with COURSEDATE column. I want to find out the new students who joined in next COOURSEDATE period.

Here is what I did:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE TO_DATE(COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('10-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

Returns: 10,462

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE TO_DATE(COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('11-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('20-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

Returns: 10,989

What I want to do is to filter the difference between  10,989-10,462=527 students into a difference resultset.

How do I do this?

Comment: "10,989-10,462=527" - will it give the number of new students?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ORACLE SQL get difference of two values retrieved from 2 select statements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276459/oracle-sql-get-difference-of-two-values-retrieved-from-2-select-statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what you're asking for ("10,989-10,462=527"):

```
SELECT sum(case when TO_DATE(COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') >= TO_DATE('11-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') then 1 else 0 end)
       - sum(case when TO_DATE(COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') < TO_DATE('11-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') then 1 else 0 end)
FROM STUDENTS
WHERE TO_DATE(COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') AND TO_DATE('20-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY');
```

That's the number of students who didn't attend the first course:

```
SELECT count(distinct s1.student_id)
FROM STUDENTS s1
WHERE TO_DATE(s1.COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('11-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') 
                                              AND TO_DATE('20-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY')
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM STUDENTS s2 
                  WHERE s2.student_id = s1.student_id 
                       AND DATE(s2.COURSEDATE ,'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY') 
                                                                AND TO_DATE('10-JUL-14','DD-MON-YY'));
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want the records/data for those 527 students from the students table not literally the difference count 527. I think the second query can be modified to do that.

Comment: @Ram "student_id" is a unique column in STUDENTS table which identifies each student